# C++, Where To Put Free Variables?

Tags: c++, variables, scope, constants, global

I'm writing a small `ini` file parser (**0**), I use some regular expressions that I have put into a `std::map<std::string, std::regex>`, it's a `const` one because it contains all I need to retrieve the data from my customized `ini` format (**1**), but I don't know where (or rather: how and why) to put that variable in my source.

For the moment (until I find a solution), I've declared and defined it, in its header file, as a (non `const` (**2**)) member of one of the classes I write, inside a namespace, which class has its corresponding cpp implementation file.
That class uses the `map`, but it could (and is pretty likely to) be used by other classes too.

And that's it, I don't know how I should handle it. What is sound and adequate?

Should I create a class/struct on its own for it, should I let it be a global variable, maybe a `static`, and/or `constexpr`'ifying it, or even `typedef`'ying it? Where to put it, as what?

I'm looking for conformity with the design of C++, its standards, best practices, and efficiency (**3**), reliability, maintainability, scalability, reusability, should I completely redesign the whole thing (**4**).

---

**Note** @moderators: I don't know how to formulate my question, so if any of you have a better idea for the title, then thank you for editing my post.

---

(**0**) It's for my own use, on Linux, so I don't worry too much about portability/compability, even if it's mostly for a learning purpose; I teach C++ myself, and I just want to understand... and I find many things very difficult to apprehend.

(**1**) It looks like so:

```
[sectionName]
str1="abcd efgh ijkl mnop"
str2 = "qrst uvw xyz"
boolean_item = true
double_value = 10.0
long_int = -2147483650

; this is a comment
[SecondSection]
str_list_item = "abc", "def", "ghi"
intListItem=2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024
double_List_Item = 0.15, 16.00125, 748.963, 10247.4412578

[third_section]
hex_value = 0x4f0
bin_value = 0b11010001101110
; type annotations ?
; my_float: float = .03125
```

(**2**) I've read that according to isoccp we should “Avoid const member variable” (can't find the link, only a discussion on reddit), but it can be okay in some cases.

(**3**) At this point, tested with a 40 lines long ini file, a `time ./test` (compiled with `-g -O0`) returns the following average which looks slow to me:

```
real    0m0,023s
user    0m0,018s
sys     0m0,005s
```

(**4**) The whole things being interrelated as they depend on each others, as I understand it. In that regard, are there any design patterns that would be interesting to drive my project (the whole parser, not only the question of the variable)?

Comment: Why not put your footnotes in the question itself, where it would be easier to read? Especially if they're important enough to write and contain pertinent information.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I thought it would bloat the post if I put the footnotes in it... you're right, I'm ok to edit it, but I wonder if the footnotes are important and pertinent enough.

Comment: If you feel that you need them, then they probably are... :)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Done! Thank you! But if you think it's better to remove them, let me know please.

Answer (score 1):

Personal opinion: don't use global mutable (non-const) variables.  Three main reasons to avoid them:

- All of the code can access it, meaning you have no control over who can use it and who can't
- Lifetime: who guarantees that no part of your code will access the global variable before it has been initialized; who guarantees that no part of your code will access the global variable after it has been cleaned up (well, maybe not a real problem in your case, but a real problem in many other cases)
- Dependencies on other global variables: when you start to use global variables, you sometimes end up with global variables referring to other global variables, and then construction and destruction becomes a real nightmare.

Some of these problems are also valid for global constants.  So, although I do allow global constants in my code, I only allow them if they are constexpr-constructible and trivially destructible.

Better to have a clear method that reads your INI file, and returns the map.  Then pass the map to those methods/classes that need it.  That way you have full control over the map.

Comment: Ah thank you Patrick! Very clear, concise and helpful comment. Good to know these things about global variables.

The map contains the regex I use to parse the content of the ini file. I've put that map as a member of the class who do the parsing, it has 2 main ctor (one receiving a string withe content of the file, and another with a vector of string (one entry per line from the ini file).
That's the better solution I've found for the moment. Still, in this case, should I define the map at the time of its declaration, or in the implmentation file.

Comment: The class responsible for parsing the content of the ini file, contains a smart pointer to an object which is produced by the parsing, so that it can be used afterwards with its own members and methods.

Comment: Just put the map as member in your class.